# Navbar change on scroll and on window load or resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this issue that I'm not being able to work correctly.

I have a navbar that must change on scroll(this part works fine) but it must also change when window/viewport is < 991px.

It actually does work, but I must scroll to apply the effect.
Here's my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      var $navbar = $('.navbar');
      // ----------
      $(function()
      {
        $(window).scroll(function()
        {
          if(($(window).scrollTop() > 60 && $(window).on('load resize').width() > 992) || ($(window).on('load resize').width() < 992))
          {
            $navbar.addClass("compressed");
          }
          else
          {
            $navbar.removeClass("compressed");
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

If I shrink the broswer, nothing happens. At the first scroll, it works correctly. How should I trigger it when load or resize the window?

Thanks!

Comment: You need help of this api. https://alligator.io/js/resize-observer/

Comment: I'll read about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {...});
```

with this:

```
$(window).on("load scroll resize", function() {...});
```

That will result in the function being called on any of the listed events.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know I could call more events like that. Worked like a charm.